# Using a Galaxy S4 instead of Genymotion

Tags: android, emulation, galaxy, genymotion

I was using the [Genymotion emulator](https://www.genymotion.com/) and I'm getting an error now since I started using a Galaxy S4 and not genymotion.

Originally the error I was getting was

> java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /10.0.3.2 (port 1588) after 20000ms

And now, after fixing my ip address, I'm getting

> Connected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

What should I put instead of 10.0.3.2?

Comment: I found the answer. I found my ip address, and now the error is: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /10.0.0.11 (port 1588) after 20000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's usually better to edit your question directly to add any new information instead of posting it in the comments. I've edited the new error message into your question and rephrased it to sound more like an answerable question. It's still missing answers to questions such as "What are you trying?" and "What is triggering the error?" which you should edit your question to include.